# Can I obtain a 2 year visa on a passport with 1 year validity

Tags: visas, passports

I have an international passport expiring in May 2017. Can I still request for a 2 year visa on this passport

Comment: This will depend on where you are travelling to.  Some countries allow the use of visas in expired passports, others require the visa to be transferred to the new passport, while a few will not issue past the expiry of the passport.  If you add where you wish to travel to, then we can be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

This depends entirely on what type of visa you are applying for and to which country.

The US, for example, regularly issues visas that are beyond the expiry date of the passport. In this case, you have to carry your old expired passport with you, as it contains the visa - along with your current passport as this is valid for travel.

Other countries do not issue you visas beyond the expiry date of your passport.

Then there is the case of Kuwait - where your visa expires once your passport expires, even if it had a longer validity stamped. This rule was initiated in 2016 - in order to curb visa fraud.  Eventually, Kuwait will also stop issuing visas beyond the limit of the passport:

> The Director, Residency Directorate – Ministry of Information, Maj Gen
> Talal Ibrahim Maarafi, emphasized that beginning 1st January 2016,
> Residency Visas given to expatriates would be linked to the validity
> of their passports, which is in line with Article 12 and Article 15 of
> the Residency Law.
>
> He explained that the validity of renewed residency
> visa would not exceed the validity of the passports’ and the residency
> would be cancelled the moment the passports expire. The holders are
> not permitted to obtain a new residency until the passports are
> renewed.